# Batch zip and rename files

Tags: batch-file, zip

I know there are plenty of similar questions around, but none seem to provide an answer for what I'm looking for:

I have a set of files that go like:

```
20.12045-s23.STEP
20.31445-s13.STEP
20.15145-s25.STEP
```

And using the a .bat file and zip.exe in the same folder I try to convert them to:

```
20.12045-s23_step.zip
20.31445-s13_step.zip
20.15145-s25_step.zip
```

First part of the batch script:

```
for %%i in (*.STEP) do zip "%%i.zip" "%%i" -m
```

This converts them to *.STEP.zip files. Now I try to turn those into *_step.zip files and suddenly everything I do is futile. I try using the 'ren' command, usually ending up with stuff like "20.15145-s25.STEP_step.zip". Can anyone give me a hand?

Comment: Are you trying to convert them into `.step.zip` or `_step.zip`?

Answer (score 0):

You can just do

```
for %%i in (*.step) do zip "%%~ni_step.zip" "%%i" -m
```